# Can't bind DataGridTextColumn property from another thread (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I'm updating DataGrid through binding from different thread (Task).

I have zero problems with updating column values.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="NAME" MinWidth="100" Width="10*" Binding="{Binding name}" />
```

But some of my columns should also have different background color that is coming from database. And I can't update background property.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="" Width="10">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding color}" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
```

I'm running into this issue:

> Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject

Could you please advice what I do need to do?

**P.S.** Freeze() helps, but I suppose to think that it's not a way to do it.

Comment: You shouldn't access WPF controls from another thread. Only the UI thread should access the GUI.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are updating the `color` Property

Comment: you should invoke the updates on the thread that the controls were created on

Comment: @MrZander, I've posted full project here:
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7dXFhBiHKVNVFdrTHN2dTc2N3M/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it by making converter.

I have made new class

```
public sealed class ColorCodeConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      ...
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Then connect it as resouce in the App.xaml

```
<local:ColorCodeConverter x:Key="ColorCodeConverter" />
```

And in the MainWindow.xaml I have following

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="" Width="10">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding C7, Converter={StaticResource ColorCodeConverter}}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

So you just need to bind you string via ViewModel and that's all. No need to use Freeze(), etc.